# visual studio 2017 15.9.13 can't use auto c++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, auto

I installed visual studio 2017 for c++ desktop and linux development some about an hour ago
I tried this code which uses c++17 auto templates and was surprised that it gives an error saying :

```
Error C3533 a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'
```

this is the code causing the problem

```
template <class T, T null_value, bool no_negative, auto Deleter>
struct HandleHelper
{
    using pointer = HandleWrapper<T, null_value, no_negative>;
    void operator(pointer p)
    {
        Deleter(p);
    }
};
```

before in visual studio 2015 I used something like this due to lack of c++17 support :

```
template <class T, T null_value, bool no_negative, class DelType, DelType Deleter>
struct HandleHelper
{
    using pointer = HandleWrapper<T, null_value, no_negative>;
    void operator(pointer p)
    {
        Deleter(p);
    }
};
```

but auto templates looks more elegant

Comment: What standard do you have set in the property pages? The default is 14 for VS2017

Comment: Looks like VS2017 15.9 has good C++17 support.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct "C++ Language Standard" set in the property pages for your project. The default for `VS 2017` is `C++14`.

Right click on your project and select "Properties".
Then expand the `C/C++` node on the tree view on the left hand side.
Select "Language" from the expanded menu options.
Check that the "C++ Language Standard" is set to `ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)`.

If its blank, it will default to `C++14`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on C++17 support in VS2017.  [By default VS2017 uses C++14](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019) for new projects.  To turn on C++17 either use `/std:c++17` in the command line or go to Project -> Properties -> Language -> C++ Language Standard and select `/std:c++17`

You can also use `/std:c++latest` and get the most up to date/experimental support